# How to set the EmitDefaultValue to false globally for all Data Members in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Web API and I've set the below property so that the default value is not displayed when members are serialized:

```
 [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string EventName { get; set; }
```

I have in total about 20 DataContracts and 100 properties as DataMembers so how would that be possible to set the EmitDefaultValue to false globally for all?

I hope I don't have to write my own logic using Reflection!

Answer (score 0):

In your App_Start folder add this to WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
            new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
```

Comment: I'm using XmlFormatter and it doesn't have SerializerSettings property. thanks

Comment: @TheLight any joy finding this on the XmlSerializer?

Comment: I think `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` is more appropriate in this case instead of `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`  Of course this only applies to JSON output.