# C# MVC 5 - json object with properties and objects null inside it

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

My project have huge objects but in the most of times many properties and other objects inside it aren't used, is there a way to not send to the JSON the objects and properties that is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are, but exactly how to do it depends on which serializer you're using.

For example, if you're using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, you can use

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

on the members, or globally using

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
```

(See [How to set the EmitDefaultValue to false globally for all Data Members in Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981423) for details.)

Comment: Should I put this code in global.asax?